# What is the polite way to say, "move?"

Tags: politeness, phrases

My grandma always says, "そこ" when she wants someone to move, -usually she just says that to my mom or me- but I have heard that that translates more as a brusque, **move** than an, "excuse me". Would I just add ”ください” to the end to make it more polite?

Comment: May I ask where your grandma is from?

Comment: She is from the Shimane prefecture

Comment: もう[退]{ど}けや！！！！！

Comment: @istrasci どしたん！？

Answer (score 9):

そこ literally means "there" so you can't just add ください to it. For "move", I think you would say:

> どいて。(informal)
>   どいてください。(polite form of どいて, but still sounds informal)
>   (ちょっと、)そこ、あけて。 (Lit. Make room there.)
>   etc.

To sound polite I think you could say:

> ちょっとあけてください。
>   ちょっとあけてくれませんか。
>   ちょっとあけてもらえますか。
>   ちょっとあけてもらえませんか。
>   ちょっとすみません。
>   etc...

Comment: Should it be どいて or のいて? Is のいて Kansai-ben?

Comment: どいて would be standard Japanese. I heard のいて a few times when I lived near Kyoto but I never hear it on TV (I only hear どいて or if it's anime, どけ) so I assume it is indeed Kansai dialect. I think the best of your suggestions is すみません though, that word will get you just about anywhere in Japan ;)

Comment: The kanji for 退く{どく} has reading as both ど and の. So i guess both are technically correct. But yeah どいて sounds natural to me too.

Comment: やっぱり「のいて」は京都弁なんですね。（「のいて」って、「どいて」よりちょっとだけソフトな気がするんですが、京都人だけの感覚かも。）

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, if you want to go even more polite (i.e. a more formal setting or dealing with strangers) you can use 失礼します. It's more indirect too, rather than explicitly saying "get out of the way or move".

Answer (score 0):

You may simply say

> どいて頂けませんか。

This however, is too polite:

> どいて頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: どいて and 頂けませんか don't match each other in register. どいて would almost always come off as slightly brash, even as どいてください。どいて頂けませんか is slightly out. あけてください would match the register much more.